# Does Ocular spell make every eligible damage spells have a critical chance since it becomes a ranged touch attack (ray)?

Tags: spells, dnd-3.5e, metamagic, critical-hit, touch-attacks

So for some spells that do indeed have targets other than self (and also have a target entry) would Ocular spell make it now possible to score a critical?

*Ocular spell* states:

> (...)When you release an ocular spell, its effect changes to a ray with a
> range of up to 60 feet. If the spell previously would have affected
> multiple creatures, it now affects only the creature struck by the
> ray. You must succeed on a ranged touch attack to strike your target
> with an ocular spell, and the target is still permitted any saving
> throw allowed by the spell.(...)

Every spell that has a touch attack (melee/range) and Rays have a critical hit chance (20X2)

So if I was to cast (and release) a spell such as Ocular: Finger of death (succeeded save) or Chain lightning
the damage on a successful critical would be doubled.

Correct?

Comment: The feat Ocular Spell says, "Only ray spells and spells with a target other than personal can be cast as ocular spells" (*LoM* 181). The [*fireball*](http://dndsrd.net/spellsFtoG.html#fireball) spell has no [*Target*](http://dndsrd.net/magicOverview.html#target-or-targets) entry. Can the question use a different example spell?

Comment: Well I thought no target entry was ok since it's not a self target. Probably all spells that has a target already has a touch attack, unless you can find one before I do.

Comment: @HeyICanChan I guess I'll close the question?

Comment: Chain Lightning probably meets your requirements; it deals damage, targets creatures, but has no attack roll normally.

Comment: No no. It's a good question just with an incorrect example. Maybe [*finger of death*](http://dndsrd.net/spellsFtoG.html#finger-of-death) because of the damage on a successful saving throw?

Comment: Yeah finger of death works! wow chain ligthning too since you don't actually make a ranged touch attack.

Comment: Well I guess I should ask another question to get the list of all spells that are either not a touch spell/ray that can indeed do so like finger of death and Chain lightning because they have a target entry other than self.

Comment: Well Magic missile would be a downgrade but it works

Comment: One other advantage is that you can use melee attacks spell become ranged and you don’t have to rely on your str anymore since you’ll use dex instead.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

## Yes.

The *Ocular Spell Feat* changes a spell‘s effect to a ray, thus makes it become a ray spell.

> If a ray spell deals damage, you can score a critical hit just as if
> it were a weapon. A ray spell threatens a critical hit on a natural
> roll of 20 and deals double damage on a successful critical hit.

This damage can be hit point damage, nonlethal damage, ability
damage, or even energy drain.

> WEAPONLIKE SPELLS: Any spell that requires an attack roll and deals
> damage functions as a weapon in certain respects, whether the spell
> deals normal hit point damage, nonlethal damage, ability damage, or
> energy drain. Such spells **can threaten critical hits**, can be used in
> sneak attacks, and can be used with favored enemy damage bonuses.

*Complete Arcane*, p 85 (emphasis mine)

Comment: So @peregrin took. Even healing spells (let’s say on undead) would now score a critical hit also? Does it normally can do a critical when you normally use a healing spell that way too to damage an undead? I guess so

Comment: @MaximeCuillerier Undead are immune to critical hits - so this doesn't work ...

Comment: Yeah you’re right kinda forgot on the moment