# What are the spells that have a target other than self (and a target entry) for Ocular spell eligibility that aren’t already touch/rays?

Tags: spells, dnd-3.5e, targeting

I asked the question [Does Ocular spell make every eligible damage spells have a critical chance since it becomes a ranged touch attack (ray)?](https://rpg.stackexchange.com/q/176595/51979)
and I realized it was a bit hard to find spells that were eligible for Ocular spell that weren't already touch spells or rays.

@*Hey I Can Chan* told me about *Finger of Death* (when the save is successful)

@*Erik* made me realize *Chain lightning* was indeed in my requirements.

Even though *Magic missile* would be worse using this tactic it is indeed valid.

What other spells meet those requirements?

#### Sidenote:

-*Spells that do damage,ability drain or level loss In priority since only them can score critical and they might be the only ones that could be of any usefulness to me because spells like daze would work but it’s pointless since it doesn’t do damage. Except maybe
For an increased range but there’s other metamagics for that. I also know it could be useful to have buff spells stored in advance for 1 party member or whatever but that’s not what I’m curious about. I was at first looking for a very high damage spell that didn’t have a critical (like fireball) but I didn’t realize it needed to have a target entry.

Comment: What is a criteria for the answer to be the best? Most spells listed? An answer, which points most usefull one(s)? Other?

Comment: Added in sidenote

Comment: Last sentence, basically?

Comment: Yeah unless you want to go for the whole list of all the spells wich could help other people too?